# How to edit commit message when `hexo deploy` in command line

Tags: git, github, terminal, hexo

Recently I've started using hexo and github for blogging.

I understand that when I `hexo deploy` on terminal, the files in public folder goes to the github repogitory that I've configured for deployment.

Also I figured out that there is a default commit message set in `_config.yml`, as `Site updated: {{ now('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') }}`.

But I want to write new commit messages with interactive session, as if I `git commit`, not chaging the config file everytime i deploy the blog.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

`hexo deploy -m "message"`.